# Microsoft Bing Translator. I need help

Tags: c#, .net

Is there anyone who has already tried to use the Microsoft Bing translator web service. if yes, could you please help me. I was not able to find useful information in google

Comment: Have you tried finding useful information in Bing? :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

[BING Desktop Translator using C# and VB.NET](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=357&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)

Answer (score 1):

You can also try the open source project Bing Translator .NET Extension Methods: 
http://maspoint.wordpress.com/2011/08/09/bing-translator-net-extension-methodscodeplex/

It's more easier to develop using .NET Extension methods than consuming the SOAP services.